# Webpack throws a weird syntax error in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack, modular-design

I have a simple file structure for my JS files:

```
bundle.js
src
 |
 -- main.js
 -- forms
       |
       -- forms.js
```

My main.js file looks like this:

```
let forms = require('./forms/forms');
```

And the forms.js files looks like this:

```
export default class Forms {
    test = () => {
        alert('Forms.test() executed!');
    }
}

var forms = new Forms();
forms.test();
```

This throws the following error:

```
Hash: a1ed74e596de181cec27
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 21592ms
                Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./static/js/bundle.js  277 kB       0  [emitted]  main
+ 3 hidden modules

ERROR in ./static/js/src/forms/forms.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:6)

  2 | 
  3 | export default class Forms {
> 4 |   test = () => {
    |        ^
  5 |       alert('Forms.test() executed!');
  6 |   }
  7 | }

 @ ./static/js/src/main.js 4:12-36
```

It's giving a syntax error about the line where the test() method is defined. I have added the babel-loader and in the main.js file, ES6 code is transpiled and executed correctly.

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './static/js/src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: './static/js/bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ],
  }
};
```

Does the babel-loader not correctly work on the forms.js file or something? I haven't excluded the file or its folder in the config file or anything, so why the syntax error? I know this is valid JS as I've written it in a different project and it worked fine.

Btw, `import` in the main.js file doesn't work either, while other ES6 features do work? Does that have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ES Class Fields & Static Properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) is not part of ECMASCRECMAScript 2015 / 2016 but a stage 2 proposition.

To use it you need to configure babel to include the [`Class properties transform`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

You can `npm install` just the [`Class properties transform`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin in your `babel-loader` query:

```
query: {
  presets: ['es2015'],
  plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
}
```

Or `npm install` the [stage 2 preset](http://Stage%202%20preset) and include it as a preset in your `babel-loader` query:

```
query: {
  presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just don't understand what you mean with `.babelrc`. Where can I find that file? I npm installed the class properties transform plugin and added the stage-2 preset to webpack.config.js under the babel loader, but it says: `Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "stage-2" relative to directory`.

Comment: I've updated the answer - if you installed the transform, include it as a plugin, if you installed stage2 preset, include it as a preset. Try it now.

Comment: Alright it works now, thanks! I just npm installed class properties transform and modified the babel-loader query in webpack.config.js :)

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

You can define it as a regular method instead:

```
export default class Forms {
    test() {
        alert('Forms.test() executed!');
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to use arrow functions? I mean, in a previous project I could define methods the way I want to, but this time it gives me a syntax error? How can I make it possible?

Comment: If defining with "traditional" method syntax is not satisfactory, check Ori's answer.

Comment: @erol_smsr I'm not sure why you would want to use arrow functions in this case. The syntax is more cumbersome, and isn't guaranteed to work in future versions of JavaScript.